# Apache FilesMatch - matching a folder in the regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-expires

I'm trying to cache some files using a .htaccess file for Apache2. I want to cache a particular folder longer than anything else, so i've been trying to use the FilesMatch directive like this:

`<FilesMatch "skins(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)">

    ExpiresDefault A2592000

    </FilesMatch>`

I'm hoping to be able to cache all image files in the /skins/ directory and it's subdirectories. However, I can't quite get the regular expression to work - Apache just ignores it altogether.

How do you match a folder with `<FilesMatch>` in a .htaccess file?

Cheers,
   Matt

Answer (score 31, accepted):

FilesMatch should only match filenames. You can place the `.htaccess` file inside the `skins` directory and it should look something like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)">
    ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
```

Alternatively, in `httpd.conf`, you could use:

```
<Directory path_to_the_skins_dir>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)">
        ExpiresDefault A2592000
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'll go for the multiple .htaccess files to save changing the main httpd.conf.

Thanks again,
    Matt

Answer (score 21):

`<Directory>` and `<Location>` are disallowed in .htaccess, but…

You can use `<If>` which [*is* allowed also in the “Context“ `.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if) (not just httpd.conf)… also [see here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html). It allows you to match for a base path *and* an extension and anything else, a RegExp can grasp…

**Tested and working:**

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/_stats/.*\.(jpg|png|css|js)#">
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</If>
```

**Notes:**
`_stats` is my rewrite url, not the incoming URL (if that makes any difference on your end), not sure, why the matching works against that…

`#` is just a different outside “*gate*” to indicate a regular expression, instead of using `/` to mark it as a regular expression. (Since I need to use `/` in its literal sense, this saves me from having to escape the `/`'s).

Answer (score 11):

`Directory` and `Location` commands don't work in **`.htaccess`** on many shared hostings. The solution could be to create `.htaccess` in target sub-folder, and use **`FilesMatch`** command there.

Comment: I feel like an idiot been trying to do this all day... Read your response and was like DUH! that would be so simple. Thanks!